# What (if anything) does ++ do in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, operators, increment

I'm fairly new to Visual Basic (my background is mostly C#) so I only recently found out that `++i` is not the same thing as `i+=1` in VB.NET. However, my VB.NET code still compiles when I pass `++i` as a parameter, even though it doesn't increment the variable:

```
++i          'doesn't compile
i++          'doesn't compile
Foobar(i++)  'doesn't compile
Foobar(++i)  'compiles, but doesn't increment i
```

The fact that the last statement above doesn't cause an error leads me to wonder if `++` actually does mean something in VB.NET, just not what I thought it meant at first. If it doesn't, is there some other reason it isn't causing an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just the unary version of the `+` operator (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/addition-operator)) applied twice.

```vb
Foobar(++i)
Foobar(+(+i))
Foobar(+(+(i)))
' These are all the same
```

For numerical values, the unary `+` (i.e. the `+` operator without second operand) does nothing:

> If expression2 is absent, the + operator is the unary identity operator for the unchanged value of an expression.

However, it is not entirely clear from the docs what it will do to non-numeric values. The docs explain various cases with *two* operands, which all don't seem to apply here.

There is even one sentence that sounds like it could be applied, but it does not do what it says if used with unary `+`:

> If either `Object` expression evaluates to `Nothing` or `DBNull`, the `+` operator treats it as a `String` with a value of `""`.

So you would expect that `+Nothing` gives `""` as well, but it gives `0` instead. In fact, it appears that the unary `+` converts non-numerical types to `Double`, including strings for which `+` would otherwise mean concatenation (for example `+"1.234"` gives `1.234`, and `+"Hello"` gives an error that this string cannot be converted to `Double` - and with `Option Strict On`, you can't convert any string implicitly anyway). It seems to behave more like a binary `+` with `0.0` as first operand.

You can also [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/operator-statement) the unary `+` separately from the binary `+` and give it a different meaning entirely*. (Or do the opposite - make it do nothing even on a non-numeric type, such as what `TimeSpan` does - it returns the original timespan again when unary `+` is applied on it, and not a `Double`.)

**: Which probably is not such a good idea though. When overloading an operator, the meaning of it should always be intuitive.*

Comment: It seems like the EBNF that describes a number should have accounted for that. I'm guess I don't understand in what context a double unary operator would ever be applicable

Comment: Probably in none but that doesn't make it illegal to use. ^^

Answer (score 1):

There is no `++` operator in VB. The `+` unary operator is just like the `-` unary operator applied to a number. Numbers are positive by default but, just as you can explicitly make a number negative by prefixing it with a `-` operator, you can make it explicitly positive by prefixing it with a `+` operator. You can use as many `+` operators as you like. Similarly, you can use as many `-` operators as you like. The difference is that `+` operators don't change the value where `-` operators do.

In C-based languages, assignments actually return a value where they don't in VB. In C#, you can do this:

```cs
i += 1
```

and it will get the value of `i`, add 1 to it, assign the result back to `i` and then return that result, so you can use that expression where a value is expected. In VB, it does all the same things up to the assignment but it does not return a value, so you cannot use that expression where a value is expected.

In C-based languages, where you place the `++` operator makes a difference. The expression:

```cs
++i
```

increments `i` and returns the final value, whereas this expression:

```cs
i++
```

increments `i` and returns the original value. That's why some argue that the C++ language should actually be named ++C.

Comment: `That's why some argue that the C++ language should actually be named ++C` I never though of this. This is priceless!

Comment: `just as you can explicitly make a number negative by prefixing it with a - operator, you can make it explicitly positive by prefixing it with a + operator` << This is **not** true. `+x` and `-x` are similar to `0 + x` and `0 - x`. The `-` _inverts_ the sign (so a negative number will become positive!), the `+` does basically nothing on numbers (even on negative ones - they stay negative). It's just like in Math: For `-(-1)` you get +1, and for `+(-1)` you keep -1.

Comment: If you want to make a number positive (regardless whether it was before positive or negative), you can use `Math.Abs(i)` (or, if you like, `+Math.Abs(i)` ), and to make it negative, you can use `-Math.Abs(i)`.

Comment: @CherryDT, um, yeah it is true. 1 is implicitly positive and +1 is explicitly positive. The results of `+x` and `-x` may be the same as `0 + x` and `0 - x` but that doesn't mean that they are the same operators. Unary `+` and binary `+` are not the same thing.

Comment: No what I said is that `+x` and `-x` are the same as `0 + x` and `0 - x`, not `x + 1` and `x - 1`. And maybe I misunderstand what you said, but I think it is misleading to say that `+` makes a number explicitly positive (or `-` negative), because if you have `Dim x = -123`, and you do `Dim y = +x`, you will still have `-123` and not `+123` in `y`! (Same goes for `-`)

Comment: To clarify what I mean: When you write `-1234` for example, then you have (as per [language grammar](https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/blob/master/spec/lexical-grammar.md#literals)) an `IntLiteral` of `1234` and before that an `UnaryMinusExpression` of `-`. So you are applying the unary `-` operator on the literal `1234` which evaluates to an integer with the value 1234, and the operator then yields -1234. Nothing is made explicitly negative here though because instead of a literal `1234` you could have an expression `x`, which may evaluate to -987, and the `-` would then give 987 (positive)...

Comment: The only place where this would be true is inside the `Exponent` part of a `FloatLiteral`, which consists of an optional `Sign` (which can be `+` or `-`) and an `IntLiteral`. Here, it is actually part of the grammar and does what you say (e.g. `123E+3` instead of just `123E3`). Otherwise, it's the operator.

Comment: ......Hmm OK I understand now what you mean, and while I still find it a bit misleading, I realize that when thinking about it in a simplified way as if it were part of the literal, it behaves like that. Still, that way of thinking works only when you talk about a literal and not a variable for example. I've seen beginners make this mistake, thinking that `+x` would do what `Math.Abs(x)` actually does, that's why I pointed it out. I think I get your point now though, sorry, but I'll still leave my explanation here because it may be useful to someone nevertheless.

Comment: Yeah, I think that I may have explained it somewhat poorly. I think my principle was sound but the wording of my explanation could have been better. I think that we're probably on the same page.